# Is IO thread appropriate for REST (Spring) service built on Kotlin?

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm following along https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPpiPzwQ_cU and it mentions the IO thread which seems to be more geared toward Android development. However, I'm building a Spring Boot RestController-based service--using Kotlin, and would like to invoke a remote REST service twice with different parameters and aggregate the results--in parallel to save time. Is it appropriate to follow the Kotlin way of using the IO thread and coroutines in place of the Java way using "invokeAll" on some `Callable`s against some global threadpool, pre-initialized for these calls?

Comment: Hi, yes, you could use a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` with `CompletableFuture` to handle the parallel calls.

Comment: I too have done that using Futures and an Executor service (I don't have the details to hand); it was fairly easy and worked well.  I haven't used Kotlin coroutines yet; I'm not sure whether they're suited to blocking IO such as synchronous network calls.